# Which of the two is correct?

Tags: grammar

(A) I supposed it to be a loss, but it turned out a gain.
(B) I supposed it to be a loss, but it turned out to be a gain.

Answer (score 1):

Both options are okay, and neither is really better. It's possible to "delete" verbs that get repeated like that: "I supposed it **to be** a loss, but it turned out **to be** a gain" (as long as they're being used in a parallel way). The meaning is unchanged.